# LINQ query to select inner list only(Issue in JSON response)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing issue in LINQ query, basically, it not returning records as per required format of JSON. I have two entity Users and And Address both have foreign key relation.

I have 2 entity as below

```
public class Users
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string FName { set; get; }
    public string LName { set; get; }
    public string UserName { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }
    public ICollection<Address> Address{ set; get; }
    public string Contact { set; get; }
    public decimal Salary { set; get; }
    public string xyz { set; get; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { set; get; }
    public string Address1 { set; get; }
    public string Address2 { set; get; }
    public string City { set; get; } 
}
```

Context Class

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; } 
}
```

API

```
[HttpGet("getaddressbyuser/{userId}")]
    [Route("getaddressbyuser")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<ICollection<Address>>>> GetAddressByUser(int userId)
    {
        var addr = await _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Select(y => y.Address).ToListAsync();
        if (addr == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return addr;
    }
```

When I called the API
http://localhost:55433/api/Users/getaddressbyuser/2
It' returns the following json

```
[
[
    {
        "addressID": 1,
        "address1": "Noida",
        "address2": "Noida 201301",
        "city": "Noida"
    },
    {
        "addressID": 2,
        "address1": "Noida",
        "address2": "Noida 201301",
        "city": "Noida"
    }
]
]
```

While I wnat to records as below

```
[
    {
        "addressID": 1,
        "address1": "Noida",
        "address2": "Noida 201301",
        "city": "Noida"
    },
    {
        "addressID": 2,
        "address1": "Noida",
        "address2": "Noida 201301",
        "city": "Noida"
    }
]
```

Note: I am using DotNet Core 2.2, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var addr = await _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).SelectMany(y=>y.Address).ToListAsync();
```

The problem is with select. Address is a list thus you need to use select many to flatten the results. In your select statement you tell him from a list of users select for each user their adresses so you have a list of users where each user has a list of addresses. So the it's not JSON problem or anything. If you use debuggger you will see that in C# it's a list containing lists. Plus considering that you want this JSON your return type is incorrect. Simply use `IEnumarable<Address>`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `return type`.
Try with type `<List<Address>>`

If you want to use `ICollection` you can use only `ICollection<Address>`

Comment: any suggestion in LINQ query?  _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Select(y => y.Address).ToListAsync();

Comment: i think there is only issue with `return type`. not with your LINQ. You are written as `List of ICollection<Address>`